# jquery select previous div from an input field

Tags: jquery, html

I know that the question is so simple but I can't figured it out. I have the following html ;

```
<div class="prev_comments">                     
    <div class="commentRow">
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <h2>
            <span> ..some text..  </span> ..some text again..
        </h2>                     
    </div>                  
</div>
<div class="new_comment">
    <input class="writecomment" type="text" placeholder="Write a comment">
</div>
```

I have a `.writecomment` event in jquery. So, in my jquery, `$(this)` stands for writecomment field.

I need to append a new `<div class="commentRow"> ... </div>`. In my jquery, I have the following code ;

```
$(this).closest('.new_comment').prev('.prev_comments').append($comment_element).hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

It doesn't work at all. `$comment_element` is just the necessary html to append for `<div class="commentRow"> ... </div>`

Any ideas why it doesn't work ? Any solutions ?

Based on comments, here is the link of jsFiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/aacanakin/fv3hN/

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the selector: http://jsfiddle.net/TAYer/

Comment: How about you create an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I can't catch enter button press, but the ajax work fine.

Comment: I've added jsfiddle link

Comment: @arascanakin: How about: http://jsfiddle.net/6Jz4u/. Your syntax was a bit off.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker it works correctly here, but it doesn't on my code. Could it because the parent of these divs are <nav> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hm7B/).

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?  I bound your add comment code to the blur of the text box for now.

EDIT:

This fiddle is the one I updated, but created by the poster.

http://jsfiddle.net/PNJrc/1/

Comment: I need to catch enter button. I've added jsfiddle link

Comment: I updated your fiddle.  The enter key is now working. I'll update my answer with the code if you like.

Comment: it's really funny. It works in jsfiddle, but it doesn't work in my code

Comment: could it be because of the <div> s are inside <nav> ?

Comment: I would say that it is probably likely that your selectors aren't finding what you intend.  If you could link your html ill take a look at it.

Comment: allright thank you. I'm looking a little bit more. If I can't I ll send it here

Comment: Yeah. I figured it out. $(this) was not pointing $('.writecomment')

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(this).parents("#prev_comments").find("#commentRow").append($comment_element);
```

If your comment_element is HTML element then you can use `.tmpl()` of jquery.

Comment: You don't need your .find(). With that there, you're nesting the commentRows